# Is there a way to scope css rules for a certain selector

Tags: css

I am currently writing down all the css selectors but that looks kind of ugly.

```
.selector1 .selector2 .item1 {
    ...
}

.selector1 .selector2 .item2 {
    ...
}

.selector1 .selector2 .item3 {
    ...
}
```

Wouldn't it be better to make something like this:

```
.selector1 .selector2 {

    .item1 {
       ...
    }

    .item2 {
        ...
    }

    .item3 {
        ...
    }
}
```

I know of the scoped attribute in the style tag but for me that is another way of inlining. Does anybody know if this kind of scoping is available?

Comment: using a preprocessor like sass it's possible to nest the rules in that way: see http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Try [less](http://lesscss.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS does not support this syntax but there are two popular CSS pre-compiler: [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). There are hardly any differences exept the compiler. SASS uses a Ruby based compiler and LESS uses a JavaScript compiler which is in my point of view easier to handle since I am not developing Ruby but JavaScript.

In addition you can embed your less file directly like this in you HTML code

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Of course you will need the JavaScript compiler that can be downloaded from the LESS website. And should compile the LESS file into normal CSS before you launch a website.

You should have a look at the [LESS documentation about nesting](http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules).

Answer (score 1):

Use Sass! They implemented it :) http://sass-lang.com/